# Altered program, ZeroDivisionError

Tags: python, divide-by-zero

I have altered a program to allow for rounding to 2dps but despite having successfully eliminating it prior "ZeroDivisionError: float division" has returned. What alterations do I need to make to avoid the error using the most elegant method?

Was:

```
for line in data:
  split=line.split()
  ptot=0
  ntot=0
  for pchar in "HKR":
    pchartotal=split[1].count(pchar)
    ptot+=pchartotal
  for nchar in "DE":
    nchartotal=split[1].count(nchar)
    ntot+=nchartotal
  try:
    print float(ptot)/float(ntot)
  except ZeroDivisionError:
    print ptot
```

Is:

```
for line in data:
  split=line.split()
  ptot=0
  ntot=0
  for pchar in "HKR":
    pchartotal=split[1].count(pchar)
    ptot+=pchartotal
  for nchar in "DE":
    nchartotal=split[1].count(nchar)
    ntot+=nchartotal
  ratio=float(ptot)/float(ntot)
  try:
    print "%.2f" % ratio
  except ZeroDivisionError:
    print ptot
```

Comment: You are missing a `"` in `print %.2f" % ratio`

Comment: That's a copying error, my bad. The problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the reason this is happening is that your `ratio` assignment (dividing `ptot` and `ntot`) isn't contained within your `try/except` block. You're not doing any division in the `try` block - why would a `ZeroDivisionError` be caught?

If you were to change it to this:

```
ratio = 0
try:
    ratio = float(ptot) / float(ntot)
    print "%.2f" % ratio
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print ptot
```

this should remedy your error.